# How to use maven-exec-plugin for npm clean?

Tags: angular, npm, pom.xml, node-modules, maven-exec-plugin

I am using exec-maven-plugin. I have extensions for npm install and npm clean. Below is my plugin section in the pom file. It contains extension for npm install , tsc run and npm clean.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>

      <execution>
        <id>npm run clean (clean)</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <configuration>
          <workingDirectory>./src/</workingDirectory>
          <executable>npm</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>clean</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But when I do maven-package it gives below error:

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/user/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.10.2 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm

[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.541 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-25T11:47:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/40M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (npm run clean (clean)) on project
```

Can somebody please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the list that there is no `clean` argument available for the `npm` command.

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

[ERROR] Command execution failed.
```

You may look for `npm-clean` or `mvn clean`.